# unresolved external symbol (libpq для PostgreSQL)

Tags: c++, windows, postgresql

Моя задача - связаться с базой данных PostgreSQL через C++ прогу. Нашел официальную библиотеку для этой цели (libpq). Сейчас попытался использовать ее в VC++13 (Windows 7), но не получается! Ошибку вставил внизу.

Помогите или решить эту проблему, или найти другую либу для работы с этой БД.

Теперь к делу :

- `Windows 7`
- `VC++ 2013`
- `PostgreSQL version 9.3`
- `Прога - example отсюда` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-example.html

Добавил в параметры проекта дополнительные директории для инклудов (PostgreSQL\9.3\include) и для либов (PostgreSQL\9.3\lib).
В дополнительные зависимости в опциях линковки добавил libpq.lib

main.cpp:

```
/*
* testlibpq.c
*
*      Test the C version of libpq, the PostgreSQL frontend library.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libpq-fe.h>

static void
exit_nicely(PGconn *conn)
{
    PQfinish(conn);
    exit(1);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *conninfo;
    PGconn     *conn;
    PGresult   *res;
    int         nFields;
    int         i,
        j;

    /*
    * If the user supplies a parameter on the command line, use it as the
    * conninfo string; otherwise default to setting dbname=postgres and using
    * environment variables or defaults for all other connection parameters.
    */
    if (argc > 1)
        conninfo = argv[1];
    else
        conninfo = "dbname = postgres";

    /* Make a connection to the database */
    conn = PQconnectdb(conninfo);

    /* Check to see that the backend connection was successfully made */
    if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connection to database failed: %s",
            PQerrorMessage(conn));
        exit_nicely(conn);
    }

    /*
    * Our test case here involves using a cursor, for which we must be inside
    * a transaction block.  We could do the whole thing with a single
    * PQexec() of "select * from pg_database", but that's too trivial to make
    * a good example.
    */

    /* Start a transaction block */
    res = PQexec(conn, "BEGIN");
    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "BEGIN command failed: %s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
        PQclear(res);
        exit_nicely(conn);
    }

    /*
    * Should PQclear PGresult whenever it is no longer needed to avoid memory
    * leaks
    */
    PQclear(res);

    /*
    * Fetch rows from pg_database, the system catalog of databases
    */
    res = PQexec(conn, "DECLARE myportal CURSOR FOR select * from pg_database");
    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "DECLARE CURSOR failed: %s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
        PQclear(res);
        exit_nicely(conn);
    }
    PQclear(res);

    res = PQexec(conn, "FETCH ALL in myportal");
    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "FETCH ALL failed: %s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
        PQclear(res);
        exit_nicely(conn);
    }

    /* first, print out the attribute names */
    nFields = PQnfields(res);
    for (i = 0; i < nFields; i++)
        printf("%-15s", PQfname(res, i));
    printf("\n\n");

    /* next, print out the rows */
    for (i = 0; i < PQntuples(res); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < nFields; j++)
            printf("%-15s", PQgetvalue(res, i, j));
        printf("\n");
    }

    PQclear(res);

    /* close the portal ... we don't bother to check for errors ... */
    res = PQexec(conn, "CLOSE myportal");
    PQclear(res);

    /* end the transaction */
    res = PQexec(conn, "END");
    PQclear(res);

    /* close the connection to the database and cleanup */
    PQfinish(conn);

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: PostgreSQL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PQconnectdb referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PQfinish referenced in function "void __cdecl exit_nicely(struct pg_conn *)" (?exit_nicely@@YAXPAUpg_conn@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PQstatus referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PQerrorMessage referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PQexec referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PQresultStatus referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PQntuples referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PQnfields referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PQfname referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PQgetvalue referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PQclear referenced in function _main
1>D:\Work\C++\PostgreSQL\Debug\PostgreSQL.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 11 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: гугл LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PQconnectdb referenced выдает меллеон рецептов, смотрел? Два дубликата на английском стаке

Comment: Эх, если бы не смотрел, то не писал бы. Там везде люди всего лишь забывают добавить в зависимости линкера название либы (libpq.lib в данном случае). После исправления этого у них все работает. Еще читал, что кто-то использовал 8 версию бд, а потом снова 9 и только тогда у него все заработало, а была проблема такая, как у меня. На оф. сайте я не нашел 8 версию, чтобы попробовать этот трюк... Да и это, все-таки, "танец с бубном". Хочется правильного решения.

Comment: ваще-то нет (про название либы) http://stackoverflow.com/a/20915117/5006740 вот тут и http://stackoverflow.com/a/15810129/5006740 вот тут совсем другие решения и они в основном про проблемы сборки x32/x64

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Ответил на свой вопрос. Действительно, дело в битности было. Я пытался поменять этот параметр, но не знал, где его найти. Наконец, понял, благодаря ссылкам, как сформировать запрос правильно, чтобы найти то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение. Изменить битность выходного проекта с 32 на 64.
Инструкция пригалается : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx